# How to retrieve home timeline from twitter in the form of .xml or JSON using java?

Tags: java, twitter

I want to get a home timeline from twitter and I was able to get the home timeline using `twitter4j` and oauth authentication method

```
ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();   
    confBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken.getToken())   
               .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessToken.getTokenSecret())   
               .setOAuthConsumerKey(key)  
               .setOAuthConsumerSecret(secret);
    Twitter twit = new TwitterFactory(confBuilder.build()).getInstance();   
    User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
```

but the result is not in the form of .xml or JSON. i also tried

```
WebResource resource = client.resource("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json");
```

but all I get is `GET https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized`

I googled many times but I just cant get it right. Please I need a sample java code of how to do it. Complete code that can run right away would be really helpful as I got a lot of partially coded program and just couldnt get it to work. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after looking at the [release notes](http://twitter4j.org/en/versions.html) for the 2.2.x versions, it appears there is a way to get the JSON representation from Twitter4J, but it's [disabled by default](http://twitter4j.org/jira/browse/TFJ-562) since it uses some extra memory.

So, you need to:

1. Enable the JSONStore using the `jsonStoreEnabled` config option
2. Get the JSON representation of a request using the [getRawJson](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/json/DataObjectFactory.html#getRawJSON%28java.lang.Object%29) method

Sorry there's no code example, I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

401 Unauthorized:
Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.

You need to authenticate before you perform the query.

Comment: The twitter API docs describe this in some detail: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/moving-from-basic-auth-to-oauth

Comment: @MikeHouston Plus the twitter library he's using provides this functionality.